# These two codes aren't executing in order?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

When the view controller loads, I basically want the app to:

1. initiate an anonymous login (using firebase)
   2, print hello

however, with the code I have below, it executes
hello
and then the login

any help?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    Auth.auth().signInAnonymously{ (user,error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Sign in failed: ", error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            self.anonId = String(user!.user.uid)
            print("Signed in: ",user!.user.uid)
        }

    }


    print("hello")
}
```

Comment: `signInAnonymously` must be asynchronous, it means it runs an operation on an async queu, then call the `completionHandler` when it is finished. the `print("Hello")` though is run on the main thread, therefore executed straight away . Please have a read: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signing in to Firebase may take any amount of time, so is implemented as an asynchronous operation. In practice this means that any code that depends on the result of the signing in must be inside the callback/completion handler:

```
Auth.auth().signInAnonymously{ (user,error) in
    print("hello")
    if let error = error {
        print("Sign in failed: ", error.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        self.anonId = String(user!.user.uid)
        print("Signed in: ",user!.user.uid)
    }
}
```

This is an extremely common pattern with modern web APIs, so it's best to get used to it early on.